# Need a different header path for compiling

Tags: debian, compiling, python

I'm trying to update `numpy`, a python package, on my fresh install of debian. I have installed from source the latest version of python in `/usr/local`

When trying to update `numpy` via `pip`, I get an error that `Python.h` is missing. Yes, I know that I can do `apt-get install python-dev`, but I know I have the `Python.h` header. To that end I've tried setting the following environment variables to where `Python.h` is:

```
1) LIBRARY_PATH
2) GCC_EXEC_PREFIX
3) OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
```

but still no dice. Perhaps I'm setting the wrong environment variables?

Comment: Try setting `CPATH=/path/to/include/directory`. Edit: actually, that may not work if `OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH` doesn't work, as I think they're the same. But worth a shot.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work =/